# OutOfMemoryKilled when I try to build my angular code

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I tried to build angular js application in my openshidt free account :
openshift.com

The issue is when I build angular project dependencies are so big that I need 1gi for the build.

And I don't know why openshift limit the memory to 25%.

I tried to add resources in my config :
But still limit to 25%

```
resources:
  requests: 
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "1Gi"
```

Hope you have any idea for this.

Thanks

François

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the memory request does not have an effect on OpenShift Online Starter (the "free account on openshift.com"). The limit would default to 512 MiB and other values (requests, CPU limit) will be set by the `ClusterResourceOverride` admission controller that is in place. In order to have your build use up to 1 GiB memory, you should specify only the memory limit within the build configuration:

```
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
```

Comment: For more details on how to set the build config memory, see https://cookbook.openshift.org/building-and-deploying-from-source/how-can-i-increase-the-amount-of-memory-a-build-can-use.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at LimitRange object in your namespace. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/ That might be limiting your max memory.
2. Look at `kubectl get -o=yaml POD_NAME` for your pod, is your configuration actually taking effect?
3. If the answer to #2 is no, then maybe delete and re-apply your pod to the system.